# how to stop li tag wrapping

Tags: css

Hi I have a problem with li wrapping. My fist `<li>` is the main headline which is floated left the other `<li>` should be listed on the right but as you can see its wrapping on the first `<li>`.

Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/ninja81/4ZG8M/

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify this a little more? You want "Bus Timetable disput goes to arbitration" to be on its own column and have the other listed items to the right of that?

Comment: Can you provide more details as to the layout your shooting for? I have a feeling some of these elements should be taken out of the `<ul>` to give you layout you want.  cool, dude?

Comment: I agree with @pixelbobby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "clear" div is not the problem (but is still should not be there). The problem is that you did not define a width for all of the `li`s that you want on the right and they are not floated right. You should also give a width to the UL unless you would like it the width of the page. Note: the `li`s are also cleared right so that they are on individual lines, but do not jump below the headline (they would if you were to `clear:both;`) Updated styles below for the elements:

```
ul.news_box li{font-size:10px; list-style:none;clear:right;float:right;width:200px;}
ul.news_box {padding-top:5px;width:600px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first off, this is **not valid**:  `</li><div class="clear"></div>`.  You can't have a `<div>` between to `<li>`'s.

Comment: I also noticed that and have updated jsfidler sorry about that one

Comment: adding height to ul.news_box li#break_news_top resolves the issues but the li would be dynamic so I can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in http://jsfiddle.net/4ZG8M/3/

Not sure if this is your intention. If it was up to me i would structure this a little better.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a div inside an li, it's not perhaps common but it is allowed.